Unable to execute bash script on WSL with absolute path, although file exists and has execute permissions
I'm encountering an issue with executing a bash script on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and I'm hoping to get some assistance.
Here's the situation:

I have a bash script located on my Windows E drive.
I can see the file and its contents using the cat command in WSL.
The file has execute permissions set (chmod +x).

However, when I try to execute the script using its absolute path, I get the error message "No such file or directory".
Here's what I've tried:

Ensuring the path is correct in WSL (/mnt/e/). Verifying the file
permissions and ownership.
Moving the script to a different directory and trying to execute it
with a relative path.

None of these attempts have worked. Here's the command I'm using to try to execute the script:
/mnt/e/path/to/my_script.sh

And here's the output I receive:
/mnt/e/path/to/my_script.sh: No such file or directory

I'm running the latest version of WSL on Windows 11. Any ideas what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Why don't you execute your script as sh /.../my_script.sh?

I tried this method, and it was able to execute the script. However, the script encountered the same problem during its execution: it attempted to run a file within the directory where the script is located at a certain line, and then it output "No such file or directory." Therefore, this method did not solve my problem.

So the problem is not that your script is not found, but your script refers to another script which is not found. In that case, you might need to show us the source code of your script.

This is a modified version of the Android NDK R24. I executed the ndk-build file located in the home directory, whose content is:
#!/bin/sh DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)" $DIR/build/ndk-build "$@"

The third line of this file encountered a problem. I opened the build folder, and indeed, the ndk-build file exists within that directory.

Please show a [mre]. It is important to see how you call the other program/script. (A common misunderstanding is that relative paths are based on the first script's location while in fact these are based on the current working directory.)

The issue has been resolved. The cause of the problem was that during the process of pulling files with git, the line endings were automatically converted from Unix format to Windows format. I have turned off the related git feature and pulled the code repository again.
